# How to wait for Angular to initialize before triggering an animation?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angular-animations

[In this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vplqze?file=src%2Fsvg-circle.component.ts) the `dashOffset` property is used to trigger the `dash-offset` animation.

So for example if we enter a new percentage in the input field we see the animation is triggered.  The code that updates the `dashOffset` state looks like this:

```
  @Input({ transform: (p: string) => parseInt(p) })
  set percentage(p: number) {
    this.percentageState = p;
    if (!this.firstAnimation) {
      if (!!p) {
        this.dashOffset = this.calculateDashOffset(this.percentageState);
      } else {
        this.dashOffset = undefined;
      }
    }
```

If it's not the first animation, then the `dashOffset` state is calculated and this triggers the animation.

If it is the `firstAnimation` then `dashOffset` state is set in `ngAfterViewInit` like this:

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.firstAnimation) {
      this.dashOffset = this.calculateDashOffset(this.percentageState);
      this.firstAnimation = false;
      console.log(`The dash offset is ${this.dashOffset}`);
    }
  }
```

However this does not trigger the animation.

Where in the component lifecycle should we initialize an animation trigger in order to trigger the first animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things you can do:

First: You set `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`, so you need to push any changes. Do it like this:

#### svg-cicle.component.ts

```
  constructor(private ngz: NgZone, private changeRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  private firstAnimation: boolean = true;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.firstAnimation) {
          this.dashOffset = this.calculateDashOffset(this.percentageState);
          this.firstAnimation = false;
          this.changeRef.detectChanges();
    }
  }
```

Then easily set the percent in the main component, which gives the data to the cicle itself:

#### main.ts

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.control.valueChanges.subscribe((percent: any) => {
      console.log(percent);
      percent = parseInt(percent);

      percent = !!percent ? percent : 100;
      percent = isNaN(percent) ? 100 : percent;
      percent = percent < 0 ? 0 : percent;
      percent - percent > 100 ? 100 : percent;
      this.percentage = percent;
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.percentage = 20;
    },1)
  }
```

The `setTimeout` add the change into a new render frame and the animation works on start, and on every changing.

Comment: Hi Flo - I tried making those changes and now it renders the percentage when the component loads, however it does not animate it.  I added the changes here.  Any ideas?  https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-fwomtf?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: Yes, you can remove the `ngIf` in your svg file ` <circle *ngIf="this.dashOffset"`. Without it the animation will start. Why: You set the `dashOffset` and Angular will detect the change and makes the circle visible. But Angular detect not the change from value 'undefinded' to 'yourPercentValue'.

Comment: OK - Getting warmer :) - I removed the ngIf and it kind of works now ... It works in the scenario where the percentage is an input state coming from the parent ... however if the percentage input is set directly like this `<el-circle-progress [options]="options" percentage="22"></el-circle-progress>
` then the rendering is still static.  Any ideas?  It's going to be an open source component, so I need to support the direct configuration use case.  I created another Stackblitz to illustrate: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-kdnp3o?file=src%2Fmain.template.html

Comment: ```ngAfterViewInit` a easy `setTimeout` in the circle components ngAfterViewInit does the trick: ` ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.firstAnimation) {
      setTimeout(() => {
      this.dashOffset = this.calculateDashOffset(this.percentageState);
      this.firstAnimation = false;
      console.log(`The dash offset is ${this.dashOffset}`);
      this.changeRef.detectChanges();
      })
    }
  }```

Comment: OK COOL!!  It works now!!  Thank you!!!  Final Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-au9lvh?file=src%2Fsvg-circle.component.ts